# Android onKeyListener issues

Tags: android

I have a editText where I want it to be emptied when the user presses the spacebar on their keyboards. (A newbie to android here =] )

```
 UserInput.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (event.getKeyCode() == event.KEYCODE_SPACE)) {
                UserInput.setText("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this surely useful to you when user click space button define your own action...

```
youredittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
      public boolean onKey(View v,  int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)) {
          // Perform action on key press
           youredittext.setText("");
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), youredittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated but actually it still doesn't work, even though I have followed your codes one by one